Klaviyo API how to fetch my campaign breakdown by date
I retrieved the summary of my campaign totals using this endpoint 'a.klaviyo.com/api/campaign-values-reports/'.
However, I'm now interested in obtaining a breakdown of the results by date. Specifically, I want to see what my campaign achieved each day.
Does anyone know how to fetch this information?
Thank you!
